# C# shorten 2 similar if statements

Tags: c#

I'm wondering how I can shorten these if statements:

```
if (x == 0)
{
    z = 7;
    y = 7;
}
if (x == 7)
{
    z = 7;
    if (y != 7)
    {
        y = 7;
    }
}
```

I feel like a ternary would be fine, but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: you cant use a single ternary, can do with 2 ternarys since a ternary cannot do 'nothing' and has to evaluate to a value

Comment: This question should've acctualy beeen asked on `Code Review`

Comment: I think you'd better think about using || rather than ternary operator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks short enough for me:

```
if (x == 0 || x == 7)
{
    y = z = 7;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An if statement is probably the best for your  example. But some problems are better solved with a switch statement. So I thought I would add it:

```
switch(x)
{
   case 0:
   case 7:
     y = z = 7;
     break;

}
```

Answer (score -3):

using ternary would be something like

```
        //variable initialization as needed.
        y = (x == 0 || x == 7) ? 7 : y;
        // y = (ConditionThatWouldReturnBool) True(?) doThisPart False(:) doThisPart
        z =  (x == 0 || x == 7) ? 7 : z;
```

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: You broke OP's logic. You're setting z to y, if the condition is false. OP didn't change any variables when the condition was false.

Comment: that was a typo! if it is false, leave the 'y' alone. I can see the issue with my z=y though. Thanks.

Comment: Removed my downvote. Your code is now the same logic.. Unless y and z are properties with side-effects ;)

Comment: Ah, no, your edit broke it again. You're setting y = z in all cases.

Comment: yeah, I see it. It's trickier than I thought. Thanks for explaining haha.

Comment: @Upvoter? what is correct in this answer?

Comment: @L.B - Is it still incorrect after the edit? Could you explain where please.

Comment: @HakuKalay Now can you explain what is better than the most upvoted question? You changed your answer millions of times just to be different. But it is as simple as it.

Comment: @i4v - "...changed it millions of times just to be different." Really? "To be different?" A user pointed out an issue and I corrected my original post, then thought I could consolidate again, user pointed out how that edit would not work so I reverted. Btw, what did you wanted me to do? Delete it? Btw, OP mentioned "I feel like a ternary would be fine...", which I was aiming for.

Comment: @HakuKalay Best answers were given 10-15 minutes ago before your trials. You just wanted to show your c# knowledge and failed. That is all.